# CSS div tile change colour based if else statement

Tags: php, html, css

I have this little project that I would like to update with a more "metro" interface.
How would I create a box and have is change colour based on the PHP statement. At the moment all I can do is change the font colour.

Thanks

```
<?php
$fp = @fsockopen("SERVERIP", "443", $errno, $errstr, 1);
if($fp >= 1)
{ echo 'Email <span style="color: green;font-size: 110%" >UP</span>';}
else{ echo 'Email <body style="color: red;">OFF</span>';}
?>
```

Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use `background-color`?

```
<?php
$fp = @fsockopen("SERVERIP", "443", $errno, $errstr, 1);
if($fp >= 1)
{ echo 'Email <span style="background-color: green;font-size: 110%" >UP</span>';}
else{ echo 'Email <body style="background-color: red;">OFF</span>';}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the background-color property in CSS. Also, for OFF you have a body tag and not a span tag.

```
<?php
$fp = @fsockopen("SERVERIP", "443", $errno, $errstr, 1);
if($fp >= 1){
    echo 'Email <span style="background-color: green;font-size: 110%" >UP</span>';}
} else {
    echo 'Email <span style="background-color: red;">OFF</span>';
}
?>
```